# How to insert the xml nodes with same name and ignore based on the attribute

Tags: sql, xml

I have a below xml

`

```
<xml>
<entities>
<entity id="147297" version="20150209161956">
    <dobs>
        <dob Y="1970">10/16/1970</dob>
        <dob D="17" M="10" Y="1970">10/17/1970</dob>
        <dob D="02" M="7" Y="1920">02/1]7/1920</dob>
        <dob D="1" M="9" Y="1990">10/9/1990</dob>
        <dob Y="1870">10/16/1870</dob>
    </dobs>
</entity>
</entities>
</xml>
```

`

I need to insert only the dob nodes which has D and M and Y attributes in table (Table A), if only Y attribute is specified then the entire tag need to be inserted in another table (Table B), how to achieve this is SQL.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Please specify your actual RDBMS (product and version). XML support is highly verndor specific...

Comment: i am using  MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<xml>
<entities>
<entity id="147297" version="20150209161956">
    <dobs>
        <dob Y="1970">10/16/1970</dob>
        <dob D="17" M="10" Y="1970">10/17/1970</dob>
        <dob D="02" M="7" Y="1920">02/1]7/1920</dob>
        <dob D="1" M="9" Y="1990">10/9/1990</dob>
        <dob Y="1870">10/16/1870</dob>
    </dobs>
</entity>
</entities>
</xml>';
```

--complete dobs for Table A

```
SELECT ent.value('@id','int') AS Entity_Id
      ,ent.value('@version','nvarchar(max)') AS Entity_Version
      ,AllParams.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/entities/entity') A(ent)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('dobs/dob[@D and @M and @Y]') B(AllParams);
```

--Y-only dobs for Table B

```
SELECT ent.value('@id','int') AS Entity_Id
      ,ent.value('@version','nvarchar(max)') AS Entity_Version
      ,JustY.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/entities/entity') A(ent)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('dobs/dob[@Y and empty(@M)]') C(JustY);
```

Both queries use a XQuery predicate in `.nodes()`. The first query will return `<dob>` nodes where there is a D-, a M- and an Y-attribute. The second query will return `<dob>` nodes, where the M-attribute is empty (=> not existing).

It's easy to collect the values for your insert. Simply use `.value()` instead of `.query()` and ask either for an attribute by using e.g. `@Y` or ask for the node's content by using `text()`:

```
--complete dobs for Table A
SELECT ent.value('@id','int') AS Entity_Id
      ,ent.value('@version','nvarchar(max)') AS Entity_Version
      ,AllParams.value('@D','int') TheDay
      ,AllParams.value('@M','int') TheMonth
      ,AllParams.value('@Y','int') TheYear
      ,AllParams.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') TheContent
FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/entities/entity') A(ent)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('dobs/dob[@D and @M and @Y]') B(AllParams);
```

Hint: Within XML any date/time value should be ISO8601 encoded (e.g. `1970-10-17`). Otherwise you are open to culture mix-ups... Furthermore: With ISO8601 you could use `date` as data type in `.value()` in order to retrieve the value typesafe. Without this, you are prone to casting errors...

Comment: Thanks buddy, Worked great and you explanation was perfect.